# How to insert a check constraint

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, constraints, check-constraints, mariadb-10.4

The aim is to insert a check constraint for the row titles, 'ppl_tshirt_size' that limits it to a few values (sm,med,lg,xl,xxl) but not an enum data type.

What am I not understanding? Additionally, what is the difference between using an enum data type vs check constraint? Which one is considered to be more mobile in your perspective?

Below are the two queries I constructed but were deemed incorrect:

```
ALTER TABLE 'people'
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_ppl_tshirt_size 
CHECK(pp _tshirt_size IN('sm', 'med', 'lg', 'xl', 'xxl');
```

When that failed, I decided to hardcode the entire thing hoping it was the GUI that perhaps messed up:

```
CREATE TABLE 'people.1'
(ppl_id VARCHAR (5),
ppl_country VARCHAR(5),
ppl_tshirt_size VARCHAR(5),
primary key(ppl_id),
CHECK(ppl_tshirt_size IN('sm','med','lg','xl','xxl'));
```

The database is MariaDB 10.4.28.

Comment: You've only told us that "it failed" without telling us the exact error message you got - we can't help you unless you help us.

Comment: Please run the query `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us what it says.

Comment: Agree with Bill: check constraint is not honoured by all versions. For example https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys

Comment: @Dai so sorry!  for the first query, the error message is, "A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "CHECK" at position 56)
Unrecognized alter operation. (near "," at position 92) for the hardcore, the error message that pops up is "3 errors were found during analysis.A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes. (near "CHECK" at position 123)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "ppl_tshirt_size" at position 129)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "IN" at position 145)

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you so much for messaging! 10.4.28-MariaDB

Comment: I just noticed you used single-quotes around your table name. Single-quotes are for string literals, not table identifiers. Use back-ticks if you need to delimit an identifier.

Comment: [CHECK](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints) is for a column, `CONTRAINT` is for a row (so can apply to multiple columns).

Comment: thank you guys so much! as an update, the query would not work despite all things. I may have structured the table wrong as I can't fathom why else but I ended up just hard cording everything, including the table, and that worked! Thank you guys so much again!!

Answer (score 0):

[CHECK](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints) applies to the column:

```
CREATE TABLE `people.1`
(ppl_id VARCHAR (5),
ppl_country VARCHAR(5),
ppl_tshirt_size VARCHAR(5) CHECK(ppl_tshirt_size IN('sm','med','lg','xl','xxl')),
primary key(ppl_id));
```

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/fEuIGjvR